# Word: Prevent footnote from affecting vertical alignment

Tags: microsoft-word

My text in document is vertically aligned to middle. However, when I insert a footnote, the text gets pushed to the top (because the footnote is at the bottom of the page). How to prevent this? I want my content to remain in the middle, while also having a footnote at the bottom?

Comment: how do you align your data to be vertically centered? what have you tried so far to solve it? you can try playing around to place text in a text box or into a table (having only one cell) if there it wouldn't be affected by footnote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just playing around a bit, maybe best option is to place your text in a table:

- insert a one-cell big table
- open it's properties

  - set text wrapping **around**
  - in positioning:

    - both horizontal and vertical: **center relative to page**
    - set **allow overlap**
- remove borders if you don't need them
- insert a page break in the plain text part of the document to avoid overlapping with document text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using Word 365 ProPlus:** (may be the same procedure for other versions as well)

1. Click with the right button on your footnote and select "note options", or from the "References" tab go to "footnote options" (arrow icon).
2. Change the location from "bottom of the page" to "below text".